# Non-blocking DB drivers for Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

As far as I understand, for the application to be truly non-blocking all libraries doing IO (e.g. database driver) should be aware of the fact that they are running inside `select` loop and should add their file descriptors to the main list so their IO could be properly scheduled. So, if I use a random driver (say https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async) it will block all the HTTP processing for other clients while it's waiting for query to complete. Should I use some specific Play (or whatever is under its hood) aware drivers?

Comment: Why would it block anything if it is an non-blocking client?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the implementation details but based on this blog post it worked for at least one person:

http://mauricio.github.io/2013/04/29/async-database-access-with-postgresql-play-scala-and-heroku.html

I think the Future instances, although opaque to the application, will hand over the file descriptor to the select() call in the runloop when it tells the system wait for a collection of sockets and futures.

Answer (score -1):

Throw your database query onto a background thread, 
and return a Promise to Play:

```
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAsync
```

Scala 2.10 integrates Akka's Futures implementation:

```
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/futures.html#introduction
```

Disclaimer - I've never used Play ...

Comment: The whole idea of the multiplexing servers is that you only need a single thread to handle multiple requests concurrently.

Comment: That's exactly how it should be done with the 'background threads' being actors. See http://reactivemongo.org/ as an example. If the driver is somehow blocking you should wrap it into Promises and Futures yourself.

Comment: Throwing your query on another thread is *not* non-blocking. It merely blocks on another thread.